# How to identify a P&ID diagram symbol used by more than one control loop

Tags: instrumentation, pi-diagram

I know that a P&ID symbol has a *loop number*.

For instance in the image below

[image]

the number is *0134*.

In case an instrumentation is used by more than one control loop (so I need to write more than one number), how can I identify the instrumentation? Should I add a further line?

Comment: According to waht code are you drawing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't known. What does 'code' mean? Is there some 'code' difference regarding P&ID symbols?

Comment: Which standard. Most parts of the world this would be IEC 62424 but the bubble looks different.

Comment: It seems, EN 62424.

Comment: to be frank, I can't answer your question, how to indicate multiple control loops. However the lower line in the bubble isnt' the control loop but the individual device. Also a measurement with connection to the PLC should have a horizontal line.